# Quicksort algorithm -- clarification

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have been looking at different videos and read different articles on the quicksort algorithm.

I understand how it works and if I didn't there is plenty of material online for me to look into. The problem I am having here is that some of the articles I found state the following ([from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)) :

> Reorder the array so that all elements with values less than the pivot come before the pivot, while all elements with values greater than the pivot come after it (equal values can go either way). After this partitioning, the pivot is in its final position. This is called the partition operation.

some other sources, ([hackerrank video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLauY6PpjW4)):

> We swap elements around such that all elements smaller than the pivot come before elements that are bigger than the pivot

There is a substantial difference in these two algorithms. The first one splits the array using the pivot, and puts everything that is smaller on one side, and everything that is larger on the other.

The second one would not be concerned with the pivot itself, but it would make sure that all elements smaller than the pivot come before the ones that are bigger. Where the pivot ends up is not even mentioned.

So if this was the array to sort [3, 15, 4, 8, 12] and the pivot was 8

solution 1: [3, 4, 8, 15, 12]

solution 2: [3, 8, 4, 15, 12]

I found so many conflicting opinions that I wonder if this matters or not, but I would like to know if there is a right way of implementing it, or it can vary.

Comment: statement from hackerrank is just incomplete, of course elements are swapped around pivot, otherwise array will not be sorted

Comment: @IlyaBursov the video in the link is pretty clearly not splitting on the pivot. It's using a different partition technique.

Comment: so the pivot always becomes the number to split the array by?

Comment: @NicolaPedretti the wikipedia page describes the different partition schemes well. It looks like the video is opting for Hoare partitioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

Comment: @MarkMeyer just watched the video, you're right - they are using Hoare partition scheme

Comment: Ok, so there are different partitioning schemes, each with their merits it seems. I think that settles it. Thanks!

Comment: @IlyaBursov - In Hoare partition scheme, each left to right scan stops if it finds an element >= pivot, and each right to left scan stops if it finds an element <= pivot. This should mean the pivot value ends up in it's proper location with each partition step. In the hackerrank video, the right to left scan does not stop when element == pivot, so the pivot value is never swapped, and that is not a normal Hoare partition scheme. Look at the wiki psuedo code for Hoare partition scheme as an example.

Comment: @IlyaBursov - continuing, although a Hoare partition step will place the pivot value in it's proper location, depending on the data pattern the pivot may end up as the last element of the left partition, or the first element of the right partition. Code could be added to Hoare scheme so that the pivot element is excluded from recursion, but doing that adds enough overhead to the code that it ends up being a bit slower (and more complicated).

Comment: @NicolaPedretti - most quicksort partition functions end up with the pivot value in it's final sorted position before going on to the next level of recursion. The hackerrank video is not doing this. I haven't seen that scheme used before, and I don't know how it compares in performance to Hoare partition scheme as described in the wiki article.

Comment: @rcgldr that’s what I figured. I am going to stick with the classic Hoare partition scheme as explained on Wikipedia. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @rcgldr it might be worth writing an answer to the question explaining that there are different partition schemes that cna be followed and listing the most common ones with a link to their implementation. I ll do that if you don’t care to do it, but if you decide to I would upvote and select your answer. I think other people would benefit from some clarity on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main quicksort partition schemes are Lomuto and Hoare. Both are explained in pseudo code in the wiki article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

For both of these schemes, each partition step puts the pivot in it's final sorted position. Elements equal to the pivot can end up in either the left or right partition after a partition step (but the pivot element ends in its proper position).

For Lomuto scheme, the pivot is either at the left or right end of the sub-array and there's a final swap to put the pivot in place. For Lomuto, the pivot element is not included in the recursive calls.

For Hoare scheme, the pivot ends up in place due to the way the algorithm works. However the pivot ends up as the last element of the left partition or the first element of the right partition. Extra code could be added to exclude the pivot element from recursion, but it ends up slightly slower. Hoare scheme is generally faster than Lomuto.

To avoid worst case O(n^2) time complexity on simple data patterns like already sorted data, reverse sorted data, a median of three can be used at the start, sorting the first, middle, and last elements in a sub-array, then using the middle element as the pivot. Another option is to choose a random pivot, but generating a random index usually involves a multiply, add, and divide (for modulo), adding to the overhead. Other schemes like median of medians guarantees O(n log(n)) time complexity, but the constant factor overhead is a multiple of the standard schemes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Worst case stack complexity can be limited to O(log(n)) by only using recursion of the smaller of the two partitions during a partition step, then looping back to handle the larger partition. This doesn't avoid time complexity O(n^2).

An alternative is to use a hybrid sort like introsort, which switches to heap sort if the  level of recursion exceeds some threshold.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort